# Why doesn't tortoisemerge work as my mergetool?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have TortoiseGit installed, and in the past it's used `tortoisemerge` as my mergetool seamlessly.  But since I upgraded TortoiseGit to 1.8.x, my mergetool is no longer working:

```
c:\Code\whatever> git mergetool
merge tool candidates: tortoisemerge emerge vimdiff
No known merge resolution program available.
```

This used to work, so why is it broken now?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [this post](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-mergetools-Add-tortoisegitmerge-helper-td7575538.html), in version 1.8 TortoiseGit renamed `tortoisemerge.exe` to `tortoisegitmerge.exe` because the old version could not handle spaces in file names so well.

According to [this blog post](http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/setting-tortoisegitmerge-in-msysgit-as-the-git-mergetool/), you'll need to enter the following commands:

```
git config --global merge.tool tortoisemerge 
git config --global mergetool.tortoisemerge.cmd '"C:/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe" -base:"$BASE" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -merged:"$MERGED"'
```

However, that didn't work for me so I added the following to my `.gitconfig` (which just changes the path to `TortoiseGitMerge.exe`:

```
[merge]
    tool = tortoisemerge
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
    path = C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseGit\\bin\\tortoisegitmerge.exe
```