# git for Windows: tortoisegitmerge can only be launched from bash command line, but not git gui

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegitmerge

I'm using 64 bit git-for-windows 2.12.2 under Windows7 64 bit system. Also, I have 64 bit TortoiseGit 2.4.0 installed under `E:\Program Files\TortoiseGit`. Now, I have try to set the tortoisegitmerge.exe as a merge tool, then use it under either `bash` and `git gui`.

Here is my setting of global `.gitconfig` file:

```
[merge]
    tool = tortoisemerge    
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
    path = E:\\Program Files\\TortoiseGit\\bin\\TortoiseGitMerge.exe
```

This setting is from the one answer here: [git - Why doesn't tortoisemerge work as my mergetool? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881450/154911)

This works fine if I try to launch the merge tool from the command line, see the log below:

```
123@123-PC MINGW64 /d/code/cb/cb_sf_git/trunk (test_merge_gui|AM 3/19)
$ git mergetool
Merging:
src/CodeBlocks_wx31.cbp

Normal merge conflict for 'src/CodeBlocks_wx31.cbp':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file

123@123-PC MINGW64 /d/code/cb/cb_sf_git/trunk (test_merge_gui|AM 3/19)
$ git am --continue
```

You can see the image shot of the opened window after I run `git mergetool`, it looks like tortoisegitmerge already fix the conflict, so I just click Save button, and close the tortoisegitmerge, and run `git am --continue`.
[image: opened tortoisegitmerge window]

But when conflict happens, I can open the `git gui` gui tool, and see the image shot here, look, it shows one conflict here.

[image: git gui shows conflict]

When I right click and click the "merge tool" context menu, I get such error message box, it said: "Unsupported merge tool 'tortoisemerge'", see image shot below:

[image: error message]

While, I have tried other settings in `.gitconfig`, such as this one:

```
[merge]
        tool = tortoisemerge
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
        cmd = '"E:/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe" -base:"$BASE" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -merged:"$MERGED"'
```

But there are still other errors when launched either from `bash`, see below:

```
123@123-PC MINGW64 /d/code/cb/cb_sf_git/trunk (test_merge_gui|AM 3/19)
$ git mergetool
Merging:
src/CodeBlocks_wx31.cbp

Normal merge conflict for 'src/CodeBlocks_wx31.cbp':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 128: E:/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe -base:$BASE -theirs:$REMOTE -mine:$LOCAL -merged:$MERGED: No such file or directory
src/CodeBlocks_wx31.cbp seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful [y/n]?
```

While try to launch the merge tool from context menu of `git gui`, I get the same message box saying "Unsupported merge tool 'tortoisemerge'".

I have tried other settings of the `cmd` or `path` field, but without any luck, all get failed.

Any one can help? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I have tried all the settings in this stackoverflow questions: [Why can't I use TortoiseMerge as my git merge tool on Windows? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190188/why-cant-i-use-tortoisemerge-as-my-git-merge-tool-on-windows), but no luck, all are failed with the same error.

Comment: The message appears to be from L275 of C:\git-sdk-32\usr\src\git-gui\lib\mergetool.tcl (on my local mc). That's https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-gui/lib/mergetool.tcl#L275 on-line. It looks like the git-gui hand codes each of the different command lines, and that doesn't include TortoiseGit. Maybe the next challenge is a neat little patch to pick up the cmd line from the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging for a while, I think I have totally fix this issue, just add a code snippet in the file `mergetool.tcl`.

```
tortoisemerge {
    #set cmdline [list "$merge_tool_path" -base:"$BASE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -merged:"$MERGED"]
    #Note: no quote around the $BASE like variables, because those cause escaped quote
    #and it looks like TortoiseGitMerge does not support such formats.
    set cmdline [list "$merge_tool_path" -base:$BASE -mine:$LOCAL -theirs:$REMOTE -merged:$MERGED]
}
```

Then the problem could be solved. See some discussion here: [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/git-for-windows/ktIU6akrCMc/ngOeHAmcBwAJ).